# Set next/height full

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, nextjs-image

I have a parent `div` holding two child `div` (on with a pic, the other one with text). On screens larger than `768px`, the two `div` are displayed next to each other and the `div` holding the `image` will take the whole height defined by the content of the other `div`. This is working as both child `div` have a set `with: 50%`.

On screens smaller than `768px` the two `div` should be stacked on on top of the other. I don't want to set a height for the parent `div`, as I'd like it to adapt to the content of the child `div`, and therefore I can't set a `%` as height for the child `div` holding the picture. If I set a value in `px` for the `div` holding the picture, it won't stretch to the whole length on larger screen.

```
<div className='bg-cyan md:flex md:pb-4'>
   <div className={`relative md:w-${imgWidth}`}>
      <Image src={image} alt='' layout='fill' className='object-cover'/>
   </div>
      <div className='md:w-1/2 flex flex-col justify-evenly font-black'>
        <h1 className='font-sans-bold text-6xl mb-6'><span className='text-white'>...</h1>
        <p>...</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `objectFit="cover"` as a prop to Image component

```html
<div className='bg-cyan md:flex md:pb-4'>
   <div className={`relative md:w-${imgWidth}`}>
      <Image src={image} alt='' layout='fill' objectFit='cover'/>
   </div>
      <div className='md:w-1/2 flex flex-col justify-evenly font-black'>
        <h1 className='font-sans-bold text-6xl mb-6'><span className='text-white'>...</h1>
        <p>...</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#layout